# How to send request without user-agent header

Tags: php, url, request, http-headers

I have a project of video broadcasting in which I need to provide the downloading option. I have used Justin.tv api they send a URL to download the video file when i hit that URL I got 403 forbidden error. I have discussed this problem with their concerned person he replied:

> Browsers will get the 403 error, you need to either proxy the file
> through your server (by removing the User-Agent header) or tell users
> to use a download manager.

Definitely the latter one is not good idea. Now I am stuck with sending request without user agent headers. How can I do this (using PHP)? I have Googled it but did not find anything helpful.

Comment: How are you downloading in the first place?

Comment: i am not downloading anything before. In first place using their api documentation i just broadcast the video. After that they provide a link of that particular video

Comment: I guess it may be a cross-domain issue.. You may need to use proxies in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can have the "download" link point to an internal page that will make a [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) call to the  actual Justin.tv link.

According to [one of the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102090):

> FYI... unless you specifically set the user agent, no user agent will be sent in your request as there is no default value like some of the other options.

There are a lot [more comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#usernotes) that might help.

Comment: Not handy, no. But he internetz is riddled with cURL tutorials. This one in particular should be pretty helpful: http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/

Comment: yeah the link is really helpful and i achieved my goal... Thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Necromancing this old thread, I dunno if the info in the comment by @ayman-safadi ***was*** accurate at the time it was posted. That was a quote from some other location. But ***now***,to remove the user agent header you do this:

`-H "User-Agent:"`